# Passing user defined list from c# code to c++ project.

Tags: c#, c++

How can I pass an user defined list from c# code to c++ project. 
I basically have a list which I am populating and then I need to pass this back to a project in c++.

```
IList<event> eventList = new List<event>();
for (int i = 0; i < nEvents; i++)
{
   eventList.Add(event[i]);
}
```

I now need to pass this list to C++. Marshal.Copy() function is not working.

Comment: "is not working" is not a good way to describe your problem. Please, be more specific.

Comment: How is the receiving end written? What function/method signature do you have to work with?